# Is there a way to clear arraylist but not deference the memory reference?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, garbage-collection

This is the relevant part of my code:

```java
    List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    public void process(List<String> z) {
        if (z.size() > 0) {
            String x = z.get(0);

            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

            z.stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(x)).forEach(e -> {
                // some operations on temp
            });

            list2.add(temp);                   // adding temp to list2

            z.removeIf(e -> temp.contains(e));
            temp.clear();                      // clearing temp

            z.forEach(System.out::println);
            list2.forEach((System.out::println));   // empty list2

            process(z);
            list2.forEach(e -> process(e));
    }
```

I have to clear temp before recursively calling `process`. 
Issue here is, my `list2` gets empty, upon clearing `temp`. 
As i am using `temp` inside the lambda expression, i cannot re-assign it as `null` or `new ArrayList<>()` 
 (otherwise it would have worked).

I thought of creating a new List and copying between temp and new List, but it doesn't feel like a proper approach.
 Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: "*I have to clear temp before recursively calling `process`.*" - Why?

Comment: Yeah, just saw that in the code when trying to understand it better.

Comment: @Turing85 as it contains temporary computed values, that can be stored in list2, depending upon certain conditions.

Comment: @DHS that is no reason. What does it hurt that `temp` references a list that is also stored in `list2`?

Comment: @Turing85 i want it to be empty for every recursive call, and emptying it also clears list2's ,as both point to same reference.

Comment: `temp` is a local variable. Each recursive invocation will have its own copy of `temp`. No need to empty it. In fact, each iteration of the loop will have a fresh `temp`-variable.

Comment: @Turing85 True , i didnt thought of that, thanks!

Comment: `z.removeIf(e -> temp.contains(e))` is a less efficient version of `z.removeAll(temp)`. Generally, you seem to have a habit of overusing lambda expressions.

Comment: @Holger Oh,thanks for your advice,I wasn't aware of it.Just asking a non-context question. Can you tell me how do you check about such in-efficiencies,when there are many ways to do a certain task ?

Comment: There’s no way around just knowing the API…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this answer addresses the issue of clearing the list when it's in another list, the real answer is in [Turing85's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920091/is-there-a-way-to-clear-arraylist-but-not-deference-the-memory-reference/59920185#comment105963855_59920091) that there's no need to clear `temp`, since `temp` is a local.

---

If you want to clear `temp` without clearing the entries on that list that you've inserted in `list2`, you can't insert `temp` into `list2` and then clear `temp`, because `temp` and the entry in `list2` both point to the **same** list.

Instead, insert a copy:

```
list2.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
```

Then when you clear `temp`, the new list you've put in `list2` will be unaffected.

Comment: @DHS - My pleasure. Turing85 has a good point, though, that you probably don't need to clear `temp` anyway... :-)